# GlassFish: There is a process already using the server port

Tags: linux, centos, glassfish, joyent

I'm trying to run GlassFish 3.1.1 on Centos 6 in the Joyent cloud. No matter what I set the admin port to in **glassfish/domains/domain1/config/domain.xml**, when attempting to start it says:

`There is a process already using the admin port XXXXX -- it probably is another instance of a GlassFish server.`

I've checked netstat and /etc/services and tried dozens of different ports, but to no avail. It just flat out says that every port I try is taken.

Ideas?

Comment: GlassFish reports *any* bind failure with this message. You should treat it as just "bind to port XXXXX failed for some reason".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying /etc/hosts to make it work.

Before:

```
127.0.0.1      localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1            localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

After:

```
199.192.240.10 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1            localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

I'm not really sure why I needed to do that, but it worked.

**Disclaimer:** This isn't really my IP address - just used it for this example.

Comment: Does 127.0.0.1 *work* on the machine? Can you `ping` it?

Comment: Judging from your old hosts file, I might be inclined to guess that `localhost` was resolved to both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses, and maybe that's what making GlassFish unhappy. If you're still in the mood for tracking this one down, maybe you could try binding to "127.0.0.1" instead of "localhost" in your GlassFish config.

Comment: Also, it's obviously worth stressing that changing your hosts file like that might have obscure knock-on effects with other things on that box that expect "localhost" to resolve to the loopback interface.

Comment: @nickgrim GlassFish was binding to 0.0.0.0 which I tried changing to values such as 127.0.0.1, localhost, the public IP address and the private one, all to no avail. But you're probably right about localhost resolving to both an IPv4 and IPv6 address confusing it. I will look into it. Point taken regarding knock-on effects. Hopefully it doesn't have any security implications.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz 127.0.0.1 did work on the machine. That's what it was initially configured with and if it didn't work I couldn't ssh into it.

Comment: i have had an /etc/hosts entry with my hostname but an old/outdated ip. Changing it to the current one resolved this misleading error message.

Answer (score 1):

This symptom occurs if your chosen host name does not resolve.

The host name is defined in /etc/sysconfig/network:

```
[root@funky glassfish]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network
# general networking
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=funky
[root@funky glassfish]
```

Check if you can ping it:

```
[root@funky glassfish]# ping funky
ping: unknown host funky
[root@funky glassfish]#
```

If this is not the case and your IP address is static, edit /etc/hosts and add an entry for your hostname:

```
# IPv4
127.0.0.1 localhost
44.33.222.111 funky
```

(use 'ifconfig eth0' to determine your ip)

Now ping will succeed and glassfish will start.

Comment: This is one possibility, but the more complete answer is that any bind failure generates this message, as pointed out in the question comments.

Comment: As the questioner pointed out: 'every port is taken'.

Comment: So it's very unlikely that all ports are bound. Plus if the port is taken, there is a log entry in the server.log which shows you what's wrong and it would be easy to resolve. If the host name does not resolve, the server.log contains only the JVM parameters.

Comment: Not quite the solution we needed, but "This symptom occurs if your chosen host name does not resolve." was very useful to me, The error saying something completely different is what threw me off

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your /etc/hosts configuration? it could be that you've recently changed your IP and left something like that ouy? is the hosts file is properly configured? (see [Used/blocked ports in Ubuntu](https://serverfault.com/questions/90493/used-blocked-ports-in-ubuntu)). is your hostname, dns working properly?

Comment: This is a fresh Joyent Cloud Centos 6 machine. Other software doesn't have a problem listening on ports in this configuration. It's only GlassFish that had a problem. However, I have reconfigured `/etc/hosts` to workaround the GlassFish issue and posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen similar behavior out of several commercial java apps in the past - it seems to be pretty common to not handle ipv6 capabilities very well, as well as not handling multiple NICs well.

Do use the support@joyent.com guys as a resource - they're there to help, and glassfish is common enough that I'd like to see this Q FAQ-i-fied.

Best,

--e (@ joyent)

Comment: You work at joyent?

Answer (score 0):

I have found on a Centos 6 Oracle Xe installation I have to check the following
`/etc/sysconfig/network`:

```
/etc/hosts
$HOSTNAME
```

In my case, it was `/etc/sysconfig/network` host definition conflict that caused the problem. thanks to bebbo

Oracle specific host areas

listener.ora (not always essential but can pertain)
tnsnames.ora
in SQL+
show parameter local_listener
glassfish check the config in `defaults.xml`

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue as above after changing my vm hostname to mydomain.xx.xx from localdomain.localdomain. After reading the comments and answers above, I fixed this issue by adding the new host name in my >/etc/hosts as below

> > 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 mydomain.xx.xx